# Simple GUI with python

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have got this code but when I run this, I get a GUI where I can play tic-tac-toe with a friend but it won't stop even if someone wins. I have provided code to pop up a message box and provided all cases of winning.

```
import Tkinter

import tkMessageBox

from Tkinter import *


top = Tkinter.Tk()

top.title("TIC TAC TOE")

click = True

def checker(buttons):

    global click
    if buttons["text"] == " " and click == True:
        buttons["text"] = "X"
        click = False

    elif buttons["text"] == " " and click == False:
        buttons["text"] = "O"
        click = True

    elif (button1["text"] == "X" and button2["text"] == "X" and button3["text"] == "X" or
          button4["text"] == "X" and button5["text"] == "X" and button6["text"] == "X" or
          button7["text"] == "X" and button8["text"] == "X" and button9["text"] == "X" or
          button3["text"] == "X" and button5["text"] == "X" and button7["text"] == "X" or
          button1["text"] == "X" and button5["text"] == "X" and button9["text"] == "X" or
          button2["text"] == "X" and button5["text"] == "X" and button8["text"] == "X" or
          button1["text"] == "X" and button4["text"] == "X" and button7["text"] == "X" or
          button3["text"] == "X" and button6["text"] == "X" and button9["text"] == "X"):
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Winner X", "X wins the game")

    elif (button1["text"] == "O" and button2["text"] == "O" and button3["text"] == "O" or
          button4["text"] == "O" and button5["text"] == "O" and button6["text"] == "O" or
          button7["text"] == "O" and button8["text"] == "O" and button9["text"] == "O" or
          button3["text"] == "O" and button5["text"] == "O" and button7["text"] == "O" or
          button1["text"] == "O" and button5["text"] == "O" and button9["text"] == "O" or
          button2["text"] == "O" and button5["text"] == "O" and button8["text"] == "O" or
          button1["text"] == "O" and button4["text"] == "O" and button7["text"] == "O" or
          button3["text"] == "O" and button6["text"] == "O" and button9["text"] == "O"):
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Winner O", "O wins the game")

    else:
        print("please select an unselected box")

buttons = StringVar()

button1 = Button(top,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'), height= 4, width= 8, command = lambda:checker(button1))

button1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky = S+N+E+W)

button2 = Button(top,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'), height= 4, width= 8, command = lambda:checker(button2))

button2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky = S+N+E+W)

button3 = Button(top,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'), height= 4, width= 8, command = lambda:checker(button3))

button3.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky = S+N+E+W)

button4 = Button(top,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'), height= 4, width= 8, command = lambda:checker(button4))

button4.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky = S+N+E+W)

button5 = Button(top,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'), height= 4, width= 8, command = lambda:checker(button5))

button5.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky = S+N+E+W)

button6 = Button(top,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'), height= 4, width= 8, command = lambda:checker(button6))

button6.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky = S+N+E+W)

button7 = Button(top,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'), height= 4, width= 8, command = lambda:checker(button7))

button7.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky = S+N+E+W)

button8 = Button(top,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'), height= 4, width= 8, command = lambda:checker(button8))

button8.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky = S+N+E+W)

button9 = Button(top,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'), height= 4, width= 8, command = lambda:checker(button9))

button9.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky = S+N+E+W)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please isolate the issue and ask [mcve]. We shouldn't be writing your code for you, because what's that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put this check right after you play a move (after `else: print("please select an unselected box")` is good and take them out of the `if` above:

```
if (button1["text"] == "X" and button2["text"] == "X" and button3["text"] == "X") or
  (button4["text"] == "X" and button5["text"] == "X" and button6["text"] == "X") or
  (button7["text"] == "X" and button8["text"] == "X" and button9["text"] == "X") or
  (button3["text"] == "X" and button5["text"] == "X" and button7["text"] == "X") or
  (button1["text"] == "X" and button5["text"] == "X" and button9["text"] == "X") or
  (button2["text"] == "X" and button5["text"] == "X" and button8["text"] == "X") or
  (button1["text"] == "X" and button4["text"] == "X" and button7["text"] == "X") or
  (button3["text"] == "X" and button6["text"] == "X" and button9["text"] == "X"):
  tkMessageBox.showinfo("Winner X", "X wins the game")

elif (button1["text"] == "O" and button2["text"] == "O" and button3["text"] == "O") or
  (button4["text"] == "O" and button5["text"] == "O" and button6["text"] == "O") or
  (button7["text"] == "O" and button8["text"] == "O" and button9["text"] == "O") or
  (button3["text"] == "O" and button5["text"] == "O" and button7["text"] == "O") or
  (button1["text"] == "O" and button5["text"] == "O" and button9["text"] == "O") or
  (button2["text"] == "O" and button5["text"] == "O" and button8["text"] == "O") or
  (button1["text"] == "O" and button4["text"] == "O" and button7["text"] == "O") or
  (button3["text"] == "O" and button6["text"] == "O" and button9["text"] == "O"):
  tkMessageBox.showinfo("Winner O", "O wins the game")
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark as the answer for the question. Thank you.